# How can I modify this RegEx pattern to capture the info I want?

Tags: c#, regex

This is my RegEx pattern: `\b\d+\w{0,2}\s\w+(\s\w+)?\b`

I am trying to capture the street number, street name, and street type in the following test addresses:

```
N1 2XQ, Flat 2, 325 Upper Street, London
SE15 1TX, 1 Penarth Street, London
KT9 2EY, 158 Bridge Road, Chessington, Surrey
NW10 4HP, 32AB Springwell Avenue, London
SW6 4DP, 16 St Maur Road, London
SW6 6NZ, Flat 19 Elm Lodge, 75 Stevenage Road, London
KT11 2BT, 11 Fairbourne, Cobham, Surrey
SW6 4BS, 24 Crondace Road, London
KT12 3LJ, 3b Ambleside Avenue, Walton on Thames
SW9 0NR, 66 Cranworth Gardens, London
FLat 5, 12 Ellerker Gardens
SW17 7JN, Flat F23, Du Cane Court, Balham High Road, Balham, London
1 Aragon Close, Enfield, Middlesex, EN2 8WL
SW16 4JF, 34 Norbury Rise, London
```

The problem: It matches post certain post codes as well. I do not understand why because I specify my RegEx pattern to start with a digit.I would also like to be able to capture the dash and unit number in the following address:

```
121-135 Green Lanes
```

Comment: What regex did you try to use for matching the dash?

Comment: Can you please  provide a sample of the desired outcome ?

Comment: This is the regex I tried for matching the dash: \b\d+([-]\d+)?\w{0,2}\s\w+(\s\w+)?\
I also tried a conditional but I'm not too goo with them yet. :/

Comment: What platform/engine/language are you using?

Comment: Can we just  capture what is between the commas  and that is it ?

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen, C# .NET

Comment: @z_- Unfortunately I need it to capture the street number / name / type.

Comment: `1 Aragon Close, Enfield, Middlesex, EN2 8WL` What is the street number for this entry? would it be 1? This entry seems rather odd compared to others

Comment: This address is also  of a different format ? FLat 5, 12 Ellerker Gardens

Comment: @ravp If you are using C# you are better of to split the file on the comma and then regex the individual elements you get that way. There are far too many exceptions in your file to make this practical as a regex.

Comment: SamuelToh, yes the street number would be 1. Why is it odd?
Ellerker Gardens, yes they are all strange :(
Jeroen Yes that is a good idea. Anyway this regex can work? I just looked through my data and some addresses are not comma-seperated. :(

Comment: Can you write output that you want?

Comment: @ravp I say the entries are weird because they do not have a consistent pattern. E.g. most of the entries are prefixed with words followed by a comma. The prefix set looks like an identifier to me but for `1 Aragon Close...` entry it does not have that prefix. It is going to be difficult for the machine to interpret that, not impossible thou. Just need extra handling for these sort of corner cases. Instead of having a 1 regexpr for all, I think processing the entries one  by one would be a better approach .

Comment: Just a little Note: don't use `\s` to match space character - I think you can use `\b(\d+-)?\d+\w{0,2} \w+( \w+)?\b` ;).

Answer (score 0):

As discussed on the comments section  . The input is mal-formatted and therefore it is a little unclear as to what is it that we need capture  . If the file was properly spitted by comma , the below regex will just need to capture  what is inside the commas - excluding commas.

```
/(?<=\,).+?(?=,)/
```

tested it here : [rublar.com](http://rubular.com/)

[image]

Edit : Tried it like this too , but you just can not cover all variations.

```
\s+\d[0-9]+(?:\w+)?\s+\w+\s((:?\w+)?){0,2}(?=\,)
```

Comment: /(?<=\,\s).+?(?=,)/ to get values without spaces.